# Safari/Firefox/Browsers can't agree on select element size

Tags: javascript, select, safari

I'm going crazy with these stupid browsers not agreeing on the stupidest things. Why in the world is mobile safari rendering a select element larger than the other browsers? Even desktop safari!!

So since I don't want a perfectly aligned select box in every browser EXCEPT mobile safari, I have to use js to change the width. Problem is it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
        $document.GetElementById('safari_state').style.width="400px";
    }
</script>
```

I have the select perfectly aligned with all other inputs on the page except mobile safari. Thanks.

Comment: I believe some browsers include margin in the total width/height, some don't. Seems there was a chart around here somewhere...

Comment: `$document.GetElementById('safari_state').style.width="400px";`? If you don't include any JS framework, this should be `document.getElementById('safari_state').style.width="400px";`. Also *what* doesn't work? Won't the style get changed at all? Is there some kind of JavaScript error?

Comment: By not working, do you mean it's not the right size? If so, can't you just change the width to accommodate for the difference? If you had an explicit width before and you're just setting it to the same value with JavaScript then it's not going to make a difference, because how the element is rendered on the page is up to the browser.

Comment: I feel your pain. Sometimes I wish I'd never gone into web development, but stuck with C++ or something instead! It appears "standard" doesn't appear in the dictionaries handed out to browser development teams.

Comment: @Zeta and Zhihao By not working I mean there is no style change at all using the above js. Not for width or any other css I try. The width is set in the stylesheet but the purpose of this js is supposed to change that for safari. I am using jQuery btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different box-sizing:

```
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
```